# <a href> and PostBackUrl both are not working

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net CreateUserWizard to create a portal web site. The interface pages like below:
[image: Login page]

[image: Fill info to apply user account]

[image: User name and password created]

[image: Completed]

In the last step, I have a link to a pdf file. What I want is by clicking it, a pdf file will be opened. However it failed, it always go to the first screen(login web page).
The corresponding code of the last step:

```
 <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" ID="CompleteWizardStep">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="style5" style="color: White; background-color: #5D7B9D;
                            font-weight: bold;">
                            Complete
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style1">
                            Your account request was successfully submitted. Please download the 
                            <a href="../Exhibit1.pdf">form</a> and return it. You shoud receive an email response within 3 business days.
                            Thank you.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" class="style1">
                            <asp:Button ID="ContinueButton" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Continue"
                                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#284775" Text="Download Form" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"
                                PostBackUrl="~/admin/DownloadFile.aspx" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
```

You see the code  doesn't work at all.
Also PostBackUrl="~/admin/DownloadFile.aspx" is also not working, it is also going to login page. I heard that we enable Javascript something. But how to change my code since it is not in the code behind.

Many thanks.

Comment: what Downloadfile.aspx return ? And why the command name is CommandName="Continue" - remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `~/Admin/DownloadFile.aspx` is protected and the user has no permission to access this file or Admin location as a whole.

You can put your DownLoadFile.aspx in unrestricted area